# Eclipse CDT: View structure hierarchy

Tags: c, eclipse, struct, hierarchy, eclipse-cdt

I am looking for a solution to view a fairly large structure, which is build up of more structures, in a tree form display in Eclipse CDT. The structure I am using is made up of more structures and these are also made up of more structures. I want to be able to view the complete structure as a tree, and to be able to navigate the structure.

Are there any plugins for eclipse which can do this?

Here is a screenshot of the type hierarchy which is included in eclipse, this kinda works. But when I want to navigate further in to the structure, I must double click the item, go to the declaration, and then open that item in the type hierarchy, after which the parent structure has disappeared.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to view the complete structure as a tree, and to be
>   able to navigate the structure.

You can use combination of [Quick Outline](http://eclipsebook.in/c-cpp-development/reading-code/quick-outline/) and [Jumping to definition](http://eclipsebook.in/c-cpp-development/reading-code/jumping-to-declaration-definition/).

You can select any structure in current structure members using [Quick Outline](http://eclipsebook.in/c-cpp-development/reading-code/quick-outline/), go to it's definition using [Jumping to definition](http://eclipsebook.in/c-cpp-development/reading-code/jumping-to-declaration-definition/) and repeat this process recursively. You will not see complete structure tree, but you can navigate it.

Comment: Yes, this is the solution I was using, without the quick outline though. But it is still not really what I was looking for. The structure is so large that its easy to lose overview of the whole structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you can switch to Debug perspective and start a debug session, then in the "Expressions" tab you could cast a pointer to the desired object type (say, a structure typedef) and from there you get an expandable-and-collapsible view of your structure.